# Text mesh topology problem, with overlapping characters

Tags: mesh, topology, text-object, font

I know that there are several solutions for fixing the topology of meshes that are converted from text. However, the font I'm using is Segoe Script regular, which is a cursive typeface. The key issue is that the characters overlap where one character flows into the next, and when converted to a mesh this creates a problem. The characters are overlapping but the whole piece of text is one object. An example of what it looks like is attached: [image: Segoe script regular overlapping characters within one object]. The problem comes when you try to do something such as add a rim to the font: The characters are in an inbetween state, half separate objects and half the same object, and I have been unable to find a way to clean up the mesh so that linked characters are properly joined together.These overlapping objects within a single object also create a problem within cycles which doesn't render them cleanly either.

I've tried using remesh but that doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea? I'm relatively inexperienced at using Blender.

Thanks

Comment: What does it give if you select one letter (press L to select a separate mesh), then Ctrl F > Intersect (Boolean)? You then need to choose Union in the Operator box (panel on the bottom left of the 3D view)

Answer (score 1):

If Boolean would not working for you ...

- take a black&white screenshot of your text

[image]

- drag& drop into viewport (it became Empty object)
- search *Trace Image to Grease Pencil*

[image]

- Search *Convert Grease Pencil* > Mesh
- *Fill* <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Add *Solidify* modifier

[image]

---

Alternatively you can use *Delete > Limited Disolve* to merge faces into N-gons

- and use like *Face Inset* and *Extrude* outline ... or what ever.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I subsequently found some adjustments I could make that essentially obfuscated rather than resolved the problem, but if I ever need to do it properly, this looks like a great solution to me.